# pdfLatex exitcode when running with timeout

Tags: xetex, pdftex, latexmk

I'm using latexmk for compilation of my document and want to limit time for every compile cycle. In order to do it I use `timeout` util in following way:

```
latexmk -f -pdf -bibtex \
  -pdflatex="timeout 5s xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 %O %S" \
  main.tex
```

When a compile cycle takes more than 5s then TERM signal is being sent and the cycle is being killed. But the return code is 31744 as reported by latexmk:

```
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 31744
```

`timeout` util says that it should be 124: `If  the  command times out ... then exit with status 124`

I took a look at latexmk source and the exit code it's talking about is captured from the provided command run (in my case it's `timeout 5s xelatex...`)

I had an idea that it's because pdflatex catches SIGTERM and tried using SIGKILL in timeout command `timeout --signal=SIGKILL 5s...` but there were exit code 35072.

So, my question is what are these strange exit codes? Where do they come from and what do they mean? I took a look at pdftex and xetex sources but found no mentions of them. Can I be sure that 31744 exit code means SIGTERM and nothing else?

A short note about the software I'm using:

- latexmk 4.39
- XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
- timeout from GNU coreutils 8.23

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just FYI, 31744 is 124 shifted by 1 byte (8 bit) to the left.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The codes reported by `latexmk` are those reported by Perl's `system` function.  As stated in the documentation of this function, http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html, these codes are the exit code of the executed program shifted left by 8 bits.  (There is some extra information in the low order bits.)   Therefore, to get the actual exit code of the executed program, just divide the exit code reported by `latexmk` by 256.